# Select a drop down option using Rselenium

Tags: r, rselenium

Pretty straightforward - just trying to select the "basketball" selection from a drop down option from the site below using Rselenium. I followed another similar post but my attempt below didn't work.

```
library(tidyverse)  
library(RSelenium)  



rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",
                     verbose = F,
                     chromever = NULL,
                     port = free_port())


remDr <- rs_driver_object$client


bgs_url <- 'https://www.beckett.com/grading/pop-report'


remDr$navigate(bgs_url)


remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//*[@id = 'sport_id']")$clickElement()

remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*[@value='185226']")$clickElement()
```